# How to get the type of a container (e.g. int, double,...) from a template? C++

Tags: c++, templates, containers, behind

I am trying to create a C++-Printing-Function, which prints any STL-Container by the copy-algorithm and a userdefined header before.

My problem is, I have to print it by the copy-algorithm, so i would need the type of the template for the ostream_iterator ("ostream_iterator")?

How can i get the type of a container behind a template

(I tried it with typeid(cont) but it didn't work - Thanks!

```
 template<typename Container>
    void HeaderPrint(Container cont, std::string header = ""  )
    {
        std::cout << header << std::endl;
        copy(cont.begin(),cont.end(), ostream_iterator<typeid(cont)>(cout," "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
```

Comment: `typeid(cont)` won't do what you want it to at all. And have a look at the Pretty-Printer.

Comment: You probably don't want to pass the Container by value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard library containers define `value_type` with the container type:

```
copy(cont.begin(),cont.end(), ostream_iterator<typename Container::value_type>(cout," "));
```

If you are using your own container class, it would be wise to use this convention too:

```
template <typename T>
class MyContainer
{
 public:
  typedef T value_type;
 ....
};
```

Comment: Thanks, 
sorry, i expressed it unclearly.

I wanted to know which syntax i need for "ostream_iterator< TYPE ??? >"

How do i have to declare it?

Comment: Thank you very much :)
 - my mistake was that i wrote cont::value_type instead of Container::value_type.

Answer (score 0):

juanchopanza [answered about container's typedef](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16992589/476681), but there is another way.

All std containers have `begin()` method. To get it's type, use `decltype`. So, your method would be :

```
template<typename Container>
void HeaderPrint(Container cont, std::string header = ""  )
{
    std::cout << header << std::endl;
    copy(cont.begin(),cont.end(), ostream_iterator<decl_type(*cont.begin())>(cout," "));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I still find [the way juanchopanza said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16992589/476681) better.